# NSParagraphStyle hypenationFactor not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to full justify and allow for hyphenation in an NSAttributedString.  Right now I set the paragraph style using the code:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
paragraph.hyphenationFactor = 0.5;
paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

This doesn't hyphenate, it just splits words based on how much they fit.  I've also tried NSLineBreakByCharWrapping which ends up being even worse.  Any ideas?  I'm using the iOS 6 libraries.

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: I did some research and apparently hyphenation is not very well supported at all. (I know, it seems odd to me as well. You can char wrap (which you say you tried to do) but that doesn't add hyphens.)

I would look into find a different solution to help you. And probably a method other than NSParagraphStyle.

I found several Github repositories but they were broken in iOS5. Apparently this is a much bigger problem than it seems.

My only real suggestion is to find a way to not need hyphenation. But that doesn't really answer your problem.

Comment: That. Is truly a bummer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently found this out:

There is a bug in the library, in that any value BETWEEN 0.0 and 1.0 does not work.  That being said, the values 0.0 and 1.0 DO work.  So to get hyphenation, set the hyphenation factor to 1.0 as of iOS6.